# What is the reason for IEnumerable/IEnumerable<T> interfaces to only have MoveNext?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, base-class-library

Basically I am wondering why MS decided to implement an enumerator that only supports going forward: `MoveNext()`.

Is it not more flexible to also enforce `MovePrevious` for this widely used interface throughout the .NET framework?

I can imagine it making the `Linq.Reverse` far easier to implement for MS and more efficient in performance, but I am not sure if this makes other things slower or puts a massive overhead on everything else.

Anyone with more knowledge in this subject can give more info on this please? i.e. the pros and cons of having or not having `MovePrevious` in `IEnumerable/IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 21):

`IEnumerable[<T>]` represents a sequence of data, not a random-access list. Not all sequences can be reversed, or even replayed. Sequences based on network streams, database access, etc - or this beauty:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetData() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    while(true) { yield return rand.Next(); }
}
```

The best you can do is start again - **not** by calling `Reset()` (which is deprecated), but by getting a fresh enumerator instead.

Even without `Random` it is trivial to come up with simple sequences that **cannot** be reversed (without buffering and reversing the buffer). For what you want, consider looking at `IList[<T>]` instead - you can access data via the indexer in *any* order.

Comment: Thanks Marc, if you are buffering which could also be another IEnumerable<T>, it might be an overhead not everyone would want, right?

Comment: Indeed - don't call buffering operations (`Reverse`, `OrderBy`, `GroupBy`) if you have a large (or infinite) sequence ;-p

Comment: For some kinds of collections (e.g. a tree or skip-list), a seekable enumerable would be more efficient than an `IList<T>`.  Given that any reasonable implementation of `IEnumerator` could implement a `SkipAhead(int N)` as `N` calls to `MoveNext`, but many could implement it via faster means, having it as part of `IEnumerator<T>` would have seemed sensible.

Comment: @supercat "any reasonable" - not in my experience; a lot of enumerators have non-seekable origins

Comment: @MarcGravell: Any reasonable enumerator can skip ahead `n` items by simply calling its own `MoveNext` method `n` times, just as efficiently as a consumer could.  I would posit that there are enough cases where a consumer will only be interested in part of an enumerable sequence, and enough cases where an enumerator that knew code wasn't going to be interested in many items could avoid the work of fully processing them, that having consumers let enumerators know when the first `n` items weren't needed would frequently be a win.

Answer (score 6):

There are many types of data where it does not make sense to have a MovePrevious. For example, if you are receiving data from a network connection, providing a MovePrevious would require buffering the entire stream just in case you called that method. This would waste huge amounts of memory.

Having said that, it might be useful to have a *different* type which supported both MoveNext and MovePrevious (a doubly linked list could support this, for example).

Comment: @MarkSimpson: I would have liked to have seen a `Skip` method, along with a property that would indicate whether it could accept negative values.  No reasonable `IEnumerator` should have any difficulty implementing a skip-forward-N-items method, and for tree-based collections it could allow the retrieval of M items from a collection of N to take O(M+logN) rather than O(MlogN) or O(N), which are otherwise the best that can be achieved via `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a MovePrevious would make it **much** heavier interface. While for some sources (array, Container classes) a MovePrevious would be trivial, for a lot of other sources it would require expensive buffering, or exclude those sources. Network streams and Database connections do not support Seek operations.

Answer (score 1):

Usage convenience isn't the only factor involved when designing an interface ... you have to take into account how versatile it'll be and how what constraints you are adding to it.

There are sequences that can't be replayed, and you'd be adding a lot of unnecessary requirements to implementing it.

There are other interfaces besides it, like IList, IQueryable. Using the most appropriate for the scenario, also communicates the type of usage that it should have.

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the pattern regarding "yield".  Effectively enumerators are the simplest possible collection, you simply start at the front and take until the very end.  This means that they code to implement the enumeration is extremely simple.

Also you can have functional code using iterators which never "end" as such, for instance

```
yield value++;
```

You will simply receive incrementing numbers until you stop.

Comment: In fact there needs not be an "end" at all. Consider `while (true) { yield return Random.Next(); }`.

Comment: The design of IEnumerator predates yield by several years.

Comment: `yield` just makes it easier to implement it, but the concept (of "simplest possible collection") is just as old. Could be worded better, though.

Comment: I use the best way of describing the concept using the advances that we have made in the language.  Many of the collection concepts in .Net were invented years and in some cases decades before.  Doesn't make it incorrect to use them in a description though.